# How propagate action to inner view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I had several situations in SwiftUI that resulted in solution that was more complex than it should have been. I assume I am missing some design pattern to solve such problems better.

When a `View` in SwiftUI has internal state we sometimes need to modify this state from outside, from a parent view. But in many cases it is hard to create such action on the view and impossible to call the action from outside.

Imagine a simple scenario having this trivial view:

```
struct ScoreView: View {
    
    @State private var currentValue = 10
    var onDone: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("\(currentValue)", action: onPress)
    }
    
    private func onPress() {
        currentValue -= 1
        if currentValue == 0 {
            onDone()
        }
    }
    
    func reset() {
        currentValue = 10
    }
    
}
```

and being used like so

```
struct ScoreBoardView: View {
    
    @State private var isDone: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ScoreView(onDone: { isDone = true })
                ScoreView(onDone: { isDone = true })
            }
            Button("Reset", action: resetScores)
                .disabled(!isDone)
        }
    }
    
    private func resetScores() {
        isDone = false
        // TODO: reset scores in ScoreView
        leftScoreView.reset()
        rightScoreView.reset()
    }
    
}
```

**In short:**
What is the proper pattern to use in cases similar to this?
The code above can not compile as there can be no reference to `leftScoreView` nor `rightScoreView`.

Some similar cases I encountered:

- Reset state (Like the example above)
- Scroll to top or to target item in scroll view (Scroll to a message with reaction)
- Undo action
- Collapse menu when clicked to another section of the app

---

**In long:**

I am struggling in finding a nice way to solve this problem. And by "nice way" I mostly mean not to completely destroy the interface of my inner view.

*Remember this is just a trivial example while the problem can be applied to very complex situations.*

One solution is to use bindings and then `ScoreBoardView` holds the state values which can be set to any value. But now I need to use bindings everywhere where `ScoreView` is already used although this functionality is not required.
And I see no way to achieve something like the following:

```
struct ScoreView: View {
    
    @State private var internalValue: Int = 10
    @Binding var currentValue: Int
    var onDone: () -> Void
    
    init(currentValue: Binding<Int>, onDone: @escaping () -> Void) {
        _currentValue = currentValue
        self.onDone = onDone
    }
    
    init(onDone: @escaping () -> Void) {
        _currentValue = .init(get: { internalValue },
                              set: { internalValue = $0 }) // Will not compile
        self.onDone = onDone
    }
```

Another way is to introduce a view model. This pattern is a bit more manageable but it introduces a lot of code. A view model can be defined as

```
@StateObject public var viewModel: MyViewModel = .init()
```

which makes it overridable and can use a default. But introducing a new view model for a simple view seems to be a complete overkill.
And those more complex views may already include a view model which we would not like to publicly expose as a whole view model just so that a subset of methods may be used. So 2 view models (one for internal usage and another for external usage)?

And in both of solutions the problem just grows when using deeper hierarchy. Imagine a SwiftUI equivalent of UIKit code:

```
class TopLevelView: UIView {
    
    var aView: MidLevelView!
    
    func onSomeEventOccurred() {
        aView.reset()
    }
    
}

class MidLevelView: UIView {
    
    var leftView: InnerView!
    var rightView: InnerView!
    
    func reset() {
        leftView.reset(animated: true)
        rightView.reset(animated: false)
    }
    
}

class InnerView: UIView {
    
    var tableView: UITableView!
    
    func reset(animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.scrollRectToVisible(.zero, animated: animated)
    }
    
}
```

Another very bad example I had was something like the following:

```
struct SearchableView: View {
    
    @State var horizontalItems: [String] = (0..<100).map { String("Horizontal \($0)") }
    @State var verticalItems: [String] = (0..<100).map { String("Vertical \($0)") }
    
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
            ElementView(horizontalItems: horizontalItems,
                        verticalItems: verticalItems)
        }
        .onChange(of: searchText) { newValue in
            if let horizontalIndex = horizontalItems.first(where: { $0.hasPrefix(newValue) }) {
                // TODO: scroll horizontal to horizontalIndex
            }
            if let verticalIndex = verticalItems.first(where: { $0.hasPrefix(newValue) }) {
                // TODO: scroll verticalItems to verticalIndex
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ElementView: View {
    
    let horizontalItems: [String]
    let verticalItems: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            headerView().frame(height: 50)
            listView()
        }
    }
    
    private func headerView() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(horizontalItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(horizontalItems[index])
                    }
                }.frame(height: proxy.size.height)
            }.frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func listView() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(verticalItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(verticalItems[index])
                    }
                }.frame(width: proxy.size.width)
            }.frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

My solution was to introduce a view model what held 2 `ScrollViewProxy` references which were injected through scroll view reader. In my opinion such solution is insane.

```
private func headerView() -> some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
            buildHeader(scrollView: scrollViewProxy, proxy: proxy)
        }
    }
}

private func buildHeader(scrollView: ScrollViewProxy, proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    viewModel.topScrollViewProxy = scrollView
    return ScrollView {
        HStack {
            ForEach(horizontalItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(horizontalItems[index])
            }
        }.frame(height: proxy.size.height)
    }.frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
}
```

Comment: Shared state should be owned by a parent component. In your first example `currentValue` shouldn't be owned by the child, but rather the parent. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app